# Getting fixed labels in R Leaflet (noHide=T)

Tags: r, label, leaflet, polygon

I'm trying to use the `noHide` statement from the `labelOptions` function in `leaflet` for polygons:

data:

```
library(rgdal)

# From https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html
states <- readOGR("shp/cb_2013_us_state_20m.shp",
                  layer = "cb_2013_us_state_20m", verbose = FALSE)

states <- readOGR("C:/Users/Tim Benschop/Downloads/cb_2013_us_state_20m/cb_2013_us_state_20m.shp",
                  layer = "cb_2013_us_state_20m", verbose = FALSE)

neStates <- subset(states, states$STUSPS %in% c(
  "CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NY","NJ","PA"
))
```

map without labels:

```
leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER)

  )
```

map with label on hover:

```
leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER),
    label= ~NAME
  )
```

I want to have the label always shown, not only when hovering. So I tried the example from [github](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/inst/examples/labels.R) (although that is on `addMarker` and I'm using `addPolygons`:

```
leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER),
    label= ~NAME,
    ,labelOptions = lapply(1:nrow(neStates@data), function(x) {
      labelOptions(noHide=T)
    }
  )
  )
```

But that doesn't seem to work, I also tried another example from that site but that also doesn't work:

```
leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER),
    label= ~NAME,
    ,labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide=T)
)
```

Any ideas?
Tim

Comment: maybe it's not possible? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55073/label-for-circle-marker-in-leaflet

Comment: Not the comment I was hoping for but I guess you're right...

Comment: well, maybe there is a tedious work around. You could create your own icons (square with state names)) and then add them as markers

Comment: Are you using the most recent developer version of leaflet?